# How to get the datetime index corresponding to the n smallest values of a column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a variable 'spike' as an indicator variable that is 1  for the date corresponding to  old column, Cost, n smallest values and a 0 otherwise. The code illustrated below is apart of a larger for loop.
I can only get results using the `idxmin()` function. I would like help in getting the index for the n smallest values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Dept':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
                    'Benefit':[2000,25,55,400], 
                    'Cost':[1000, 500, 1500, 2000]}) 
# Let's create an index using Timestamps 
index_ = [pd.Timestamp('01-06-2018'), pd.Timestamp('04-06-2018'), 
          pd.Timestamp('07-06-2018'), pd.Timestamp('10-06-2018')] 

df3.index = index_
print(df3) 

df3.index = index_
print(df3)
df3['spike'] = np.where(df3.index.isin(lookup), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Have you defined `lookup` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sort, then you can get the top-3 with standard Python / numpy array slicing.

```py
low_cost = df3.sort_values('Cost')[:3]
low_cost
#            Dept  Benefit  Cost
# 2018-04-06    A       25   500
# 2018-01-06    A     2000  1000
# 2018-07-06    B       55  1500
```

To get the `spike` column, for efficiency I would recommend a join.

```py
spikes = low_cost.assign(spike=1)[['spike']]                                                                                                                                                                                         
spikes                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#             spike
# 2018-04-06      1
# 2018-01-06      1
# 2018-07-06      1

df3.join(spikes, how='left').fillna(0)                                                                                                                                                                                               
#            Dept  Benefit  Cost  spike
# 2018-01-06    A     2000  1000    1.0
# 2018-04-06    A       25   500    1.0
# 2018-07-06    B       55  1500    1.0
# 2018-10-06    B      400  2000    0.0
```